# How to make a button to find the nearest marker I manually put on Google Maps?

Tags: java, android, location, marker

So i am struggling how to make this `button` "btnFindCybercafe" works. i just want this `button` to show nearest `marker` about **10km** from current location.

**Below is my map java code**

```
public class mapCybercafe extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    protected GoogleMap LokasiUser;
    private static final int LOCATION_REQUEST = 500;
    protected Marker LokasiCybercafe;

    final LatLng NOBLENATION = new LatLng(3.556744, 98.677177 );
    final LatLng H2NET       = new LatLng(3.534811, 98.591373 );
    final LatLng BRITANNIA   = new LatLng(3.572011, 98.698239 );
    final LatLng ICAFEMEDAN  = new LatLng(3.598079, 98.663644 );
    final LatLng MILALAMAS   = new LatLng(3.592356, 98.685277 );
    final LatLng CYPRESSNET  = new LatLng(3.555556, 98.633377 );
    final LatLng LASVEGASNET = new LatLng(3.572083, 98.694061 );

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test_map);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment
        final SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        mMap.clear();


        Button btnAbout = findViewById(R.id.btn_about);
        Button btnHelp = findViewById(R.id.btn_help);
        Button btnFindCybercafe = findViewById(R.id.btn_FindCybercafe);


        btnAbout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(View v) {
                                            Intent intentAbout = new Intent(mapCybercafe.this, AboutActivity.class);
                                            startActivity(intentAbout);
                                        }
                                    }

        );
        btnHelp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                       @Override
                                       public void onClick(View v) {
                                           Intent intentAbout = new Intent(mapCybercafe.this, HelpActivity.class);
                                           startActivity(intentAbout);
                                       }
                                   }

        );
        btnFindCybercafe.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener(){
                                                 @Override
                                                 public void onClick(View v) {
                                                     do {

                                                     }
                                                 }
                                             }
        );
    }

    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        LokasiUser = googleMap;
        // realtime user location
        LokasiUser.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission
                (this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, LOCATION_REQUEST);
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;

        }
        LokasiUser.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        // Add a marker of cybercafe in layout
        LokasiCybercafe = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(LASVEGASNET).title("Las Vegas Net CYBERCAFE").snippet("i5, 8GB RAM, Nvidia GEFORCE 1050"));

        LokasiCybercafe = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(NOBLENATION).title("NOBLENATION CYBERCAFE").snippet("i5, 16GB RAM, Nvidia GEFORCE 1050Ti"));

        LokasiCybercafe = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(H2NET).title("H2-NET CYBERCAFE").snippet("AMD RYZEN, 8GB RAM, Nvidia GEFORCE 1020Ti"));

        LokasiCybercafe = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(BRITANNIA).title("BRITANNIA-NET CYBERCAFE").snippet("i3, 8GB RAM, Nvidia GEFORCE 980Ti"));

        LokasiCybercafe = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(ICAFEMEDAN).title("iCAFE-MEDAN ").snippet("i3, 4GB RAM, Nvidia GEFORCE 980"));

        LokasiCybercafe = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(MILALAMAS).title("MILALAMAS-NET CYBERCAFE").snippet("i5, 8GB RAM, Nvidia GEFORCE 1060Ti"));

        LokasiCybercafe = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(CYPRESSNET).title("CYPRESS-NET CYBERCAFE").snippet("i3, 4GB RAM, Nvidia GEFORCE 970"));

    }
    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case LOCATION_REQUEST:
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

I really need someone to help me because my deadline is tomorrow.

Comment: `I really need someone to help me because my deadline is tomorrow.` Welcome to SO. We are all free volunteers, here. We don't accept urgencies, all the questions have the very same priority to us. If anyone has a solution for you s/he will provide it. But don't hurry us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First store all your locations into an arrayList. Lets call it locationList. So in your locationList you have all the locations where you have put a marker.

Now consider you got the current location and you stored that in the variable name
currentLocation.

Now you have to find out the nearest marker. To do that you need to calculate the distance between each location to currentLocation. So first create a method which return the distance in meter. Here is the code for the distance.

```
private double getDistanceInMeter(LatLng start, LatLng end) {
    Location startPoint=new Location("locationA");
    startPoint.setLatitude(start.latitude);
    startPoint.setLongitude(start.longitude);

    Location endPoint=new Location("locationB");
    endPoint.setLatitude(end.latitude);
    endPoint.setLongitude(end.longitude);

    double distance=startPoint.distanceTo(endPoint);

    return distance;
}
```

Now consider  two variables one for distance tracking and another is for index of the location which has minimum distance.

Now we are going to run a loop to calculate each distance

```
double distance = 0;
 int nearestLocationIndex = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i<locationList.size(); i++) {
        double currentDistance = getDistanceInMeter(locationList.get(i), currentLocation);

        if(i == 0 ) { // Initially we are assuming first position is the nearest
            distance = currentDistance;
            nearestLocationIndex = i;
        } else {
            if(currentDistance < distance) {
                distance = currentDistance;
                nearestLocationIndex = i;
            }
        }

    }
```

So now you know which location is nearest because you have the index of that location.

```
LatLng nearestLocation = locationList(nearestLocationIndex);
```

I hope you got an idea to how to implement that.

Comment: thankyou so much dude, i appreciate you answer my question and its open my mind how to solve my problem. im sorry for the bad writing code because im a newbie in android programming

Comment: @donisazaly Please select the answer as the right answer if you think.